# String to an array and then foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a variable string which is passed to an and array then foreach that just does not want to work. Below is the code im using.

```
$explode = $_obj->getModDependencies();
//this variable will returns/echos the string as @ModA,@Mod_b,@Mod3 etc (yes @ is in each value)
```

and the foreach and array php code im using

```
$arr = array($explode);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
echo '<a href="'.$this->getUrl().'mod?mod_id='.$value.'">'.$value.'</a>';
}
```

if i use the above code it echos one hyperlink with each value at the end of it (http://myurl/mod?mod_id=@ModA,@Mod_b,@Mod3) but i want to echo each hyperlink for each value.

Which would be

http://myurl/mod?mod_id=@ModA

http://myurl/mod?mod_id=@Mod_b

and so forth.

But if i place the actual variable output string directly into the array it echos out how i want it (see below code that works)

```
$arr = array(@ModA,@Mod_b,@Mod3);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
echo '<a href="'.$this->getUrl().'mod?mod_id='.$value.'">'.$value.'</a>';
}
```

Any help wold be awesome!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = array($explode);
```

Thats the issue, just by saying something is within `array()` doesnt really make it an array as you expect it to be. You only gave it 1 argument.

You also mentioned the value of `$explode` is like this `@ModA,@Mod_b,@Mod3`. Just by naming something `$explode` doesn't explode it. You have to explode it yourself

```
$arr=explode(",","@ModA,@Mod_b,@Mod3"); 
//$arr=explode(",",$explode) in your case
```

Once that is done, your loop is already fine

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
echo '<a href="'.$this->getUrl().'mod?mod_id='.$value.'">'.$value.'</a>';
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/243026)**

Comment: Thanks Man!! Went with $arr=explode(",","".$_obj->getModDependencies().""); and achieved what i needed.

Comment: You don't need quotes around that variable. You can change that line to `$arr=explode(",",$_obj->getModDependencies());`

Answer (score 1):

When your variable `$explode` will be a string as `'@ModA,@Mod_b,@Mod3'` then you have to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it.

```
$arr = explode(',', $explode);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo '<a href="'.$this->getUrl().'mod?mod_id='.$value.'">'.$value.'</a>';
}
```